# Simple Firestore query doesn't give me complete documents in a collection

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

My Firestore data model looks like this

> Organizations/{orgId}/cloudAccounts/{cloudAccountId}/resources/{resourceId}

I am running a simple query like this

```
let documents = await db.collection("Organizations")
    .doc("orgIdabc")
    .collection("cloudAccounts")
    .doc("cloudAccountIdabc")
    .collection("resources")
    .get();

console.log("LENGTH: ", documents.docs.length);
```

Now the problem is that when I try to log the document length, it's always giving me a different length. I'll share the output as well.

```
     LENGTH:  18
  LENGTH:  19
 LENGTH:  19
  LENGTH:  6
  LENGTH:  3
  LENGTH:  19
  LENGTH:  12
  LENGTH:  19
  LENGTH:  19
```

Now the actual length is 19, but as you can see I am getting different lengths.
I've no idea what's the problem here, any help would be really appreciated.

**Updated**
as per request I am adding the complete code snippet 
Also I've come to know that this problem is only happening on Admin SDK and not the client SDK

```
const { db } = require("./firestore");
const functions = require("firebase-functions");

exports.runScanOnAllCloudAccounts = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  runScanOnAllCA();
  return res.status(200);
});

async function runScanOnAllCA() {
  try {
   for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
let documents = await db.collection("Organizations")
    .doc("orgIdabc")
    .collection("cloudAccounts")
    .doc("cloudAccountIdabc")
    .collection("resources")
    .get();

console.log("LENGTH: ", documents.docs.length);
     }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("err: ", err);
  }
}
```

**Update 02** ===========>
I've updated the code to use Promise() heavy approach, as recommended by some users and I still get different document lengths. 
I feel that people are missing the point here, Promises are just a way to run asynchronous code, we can resolve this by using async await that was already being used in the previous version of the code.
Still the following code snippet doesn't solve the problem.

```
const { db } = require("./firestore");
const functions = require("firebase-functions");

exports.runScanOnAllCloudAccounts = functions.https.onRequest(
  async (req, res) => {
    runScanOnAllCA(res)
      .then(resolve => {
        console.log(resolve);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
    // return res.status(200);
  }
);

async function runScanOnAllCA(res) {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    db.collection("Organizations")
      .doc("sumair-hello-world_axtr8")
      .collection("cloudAccounts")
      .doc("4ZQgjt94pvEQTlvxSJ75")
      .collection("resources")
      .get()
      .then(querySnapshot => {
        resolve(querySnapshot.docs.length);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        reject(err);
      });
  });
}
```

Comment: The logged output doesn't look the same as the actual code snippet? `document length:` != `LENGTH:` Chances are, there's something wrong in your actual code snippet.

Comment: Its the same. I just changed the length and document length text in the console and nothing else

Comment: it may be a sync issue, since your `console.log()` is directly after the await of documents fetch, try adding your `console.log` to `.get().then()` like this: `.get().then((QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
    console.log("LENGTH: ", snapshot.documents.length);
  });` and let me know if it works

Comment: No, unfortunately it didn't work. The output is as follows:

`LENGTH:  6
>  LENGTH:  4
>  LENGTH:  8
>  LENGTH:  3
>  LENGTH:  9
>  LENGTH:  12
>  LENGTH:  11
>  LENGTH:  11
>  LENGTH:  5
>  LENGTH:  4
>  LENGTH:  13
>  LENGTH:  12
>  LENGTH:  12
>  LENGTH:  6`

Again actual length is 19

Comment: I've just found out that this is happening with any collection length that I try to check. Whether it be a parent collection of a child one. 
Something wrong with my Admin SDK may be ?

Comment: Can you show your entire code and not only a snippet?

Comment: Sure let me add that in my question

Comment: @RenaudTarnec please check

Comment: You will need to learn how to use JavaScript promises.  Code in Cloud Functions should only send a response after all the asynchronous work is complete.  Firestore queries are asynchronous and return a promise that resolves only after the query is done.  You will need to use these to determine when to send the response.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, by using `await` in the query does signify that a Promise returned should be resolved() by using the await keyword. This is one of the recommended way of using Promises() in JS / Cloud Functions not?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.firestore) in order to interact with Firestore from a Cloud Function.

Secondly, it is known that using await in loops can lead to "erratic" results. See, for example, https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=for+and+await

Finally, note that you are incorrectly calling your asynchronous `runScanOnAllCA()` function. You should either use [`then()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) or make your Cloud Function `async` and use `await`, see the code below.

You should adapt your CF as follows for using the Admin SDK:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp();

exports.runScanOnAllCloudAccounts = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
    await runScanOnAllCA();   //<--- Note the await here and the async above, since you are calling an async function
    res.status(200);   //<--- No need to use return in an HTTPS Cloud Function, just terminate it with res.redirect(), res.send(), or res.end().
});

async function runScanOnAllCA() {
    try {
        const db = admin.firestore();

        //The loop was removed. Use another way if needed, e.g. Promise.all() or the techniques presented in the links above.

        let documents = await db.collection("Organizations")
                .doc("orgIdabc")
                .collection("cloudAccounts")
                .doc("cloudAccountIdabc")
                .collection("resources")
                .get();

        console.log("LENGTH: ", documents.docs.length);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("err: ", err);
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. I am using the `Admin SDK` for my cloud function, it's being imported from the `{db}` reference in the start.
2. Actually for loops are the safest when using them with `async / await`, as described in the articles that came from the chrome search you shared. 
3. Even when doing async on the `runScanOnAllCA()` doesn't resolve the issue.